# .netcore Session Secure cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, session-cookies

Using aspnetcore.session 1.1 I am setting the cookie as secure:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
        {
          options.CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });
```

yet the cookie is not marked as secure:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you clear the prior cookie?

Comment: Yes think that was it. code works as expected

Answer (score 9):

Asof aspnetcore 2

`options.CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;` is obsolete you need you need to use

```
services.AddSession(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                });
```

Answer (score 4):

Clearing the prior cookie solved issue. Code worked as expected.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, even though it might seem obvious, thank you